# how to call custom fonts in shopify this is not work like before

Tags: shopify, webfonts

```
@font-face { font-family: 'chunkfive_printregular'; src: url( {{ chunk_five_print-webfont.woff2 | asset_url }} ) format('woff2'), url({{ chunk_five_print-webfont.woff | asset_url }} ) format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
```

like this not work now please help me after Shopify 2.0 update

Comment: Need more information like which file code is added? or snapshot of code

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions about that too.
There are some warnings in the browser console.

> Failed to decode downloaded font:  OTS parsing error: DSIG:
> misaligned table

Newly built stores will appear recently, which has never happened before.

My style code:

```
<style>
@font-face {

    font-family: Sanctuary;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("{{ 'Sanctuary.ttf' | asset_url }}");
    font-display: swap;

}

.announcement-bar__message.h5 {

    font-family: Sanctuary;

}
</style>
```

Comment: The function of uploading a font file in a custom template causes problems in the uploaded font file.
The solution now is to upload the font file from the file in the Settings.